# Javascript: can't override toString method in very simple class?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I'm trying to override the 'toString' method in a very simple class.  I've tried multiple approaches, but am not getting the output I would expect

```
function foo(arg){
    this.n=20;
    this.x=arg;
}

foo.prototype.toString = function(){
    return this.x.toString();
};

c = new foo(5);

console.log(c);
```

I expect to see the output as "5" but instead the output I get is the default "{ n:20, x:5 }"

What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `cell`? You mean `foo`?

Comment: `console.log` doesn't use `toString`

Comment: Try `alert(c)`. Or `console.log(String(c))`. `c` really is an object, and the console shows you that.

Comment: Use `{` for function body in `function foo(arg)(`

Comment: *"... the default `"{ n:20, x:5 }"`"* The default `toString` would have given you `"[object Object]"`, not `"{ n:20, x:5 }"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some browser might use `toString` for `console.log`, but some show the value in a more usable form. In Firefox for example you get a link to a view of the object properties.

If you use the object somewhere there a string is expected, it will use the `ToString` method that you specified:

```js
function foo(arg) {
    this.n=20;
    this.x=arg;
}

foo.prototype.toString = function(){
    return this.x.toString();
};

c = new foo(5);

document.write(c);
```

Comment: Aah, thank you! So what can I call so that the 'toString' function is called when printing to the console? for clarity I'm using an online javascript interpreter repl.it

Comment: @Paul: You can call `toString`: `console.log(c.toString());`.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question - wasn't sure if it would be that simple :D

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: I don't know who down-voted you but this was the complete answer to my question - thanks again! :)

Answer (score 4):

Only declaring prototype won't work until you call it:

```
function foo(arg) {
    this.n=20;
    this.x=arg;
}

foo.prototype.toString = function(){
    return this.x.toString();
};

c = new foo(5);

console.log(c.toString());
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^----------- the main change is here
```

Comment: It was just a typo, sorry for the confusion - I've fixed the code in the question....

Answer (score 1):

As Vicky said.

or you can implicitly cast to a string

```
console.log(c+'');
```

This will invoke the toString method

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3z8dd97w/)** here